# jQuery Action when at certain point in HTML video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I wanted it so that the full video was enabled, but by default, it would loop a certain portion of the video over and over.

So like if it's a 30 second video, but it's set to play 5 seconds of video starting at 10 seconds, it would play those 5 seconds starting 10s into the video, then loop back to 10s again and play those same 5 seconds over.

How would I monitor the video with jquery so that I could fire off the event when the seeker is at a certain point in the video?

Comment: Please add your code here.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: `ontimeupdate` event is there.

Comment: worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

this code will allow you to set up two loopable parts of a video, so should give you enough of a solution to get started. Not jQuery based, but easy enough to convert to that model (just not what I had to hand)

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" muted preload="metadata" >
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<button onclick="repeat(1,3)">1-3</button>
<button onclick="repeat(5,7)">5-7</button>

<script>
var funcLoop
function repeat(startTime, endTime) {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', funcLoop, false);
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', funcLoop=function(){
        if (video.currentTime < startTime) {
            video.currentTime = startTime;
        }
        if (video.currentTime >= endTime) {
            video.currentTime = startTime;
        }}, false);
    video.play();
}
</script>
```